# no visual output after uploading file

Tags: php, file, upload, echo

So i've been troubleshooting for a while now, and I still just don't get it...

I'm trying to upload a file to a folder via a form:

```
<form id="insert_movie" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I evaluate this form via 'upload_file.php':

```
//Upload the image
$allow = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

$todir = 'images/';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
    {
        $info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file

        if ( in_array( end($info), $allow) ) // is this file allowed
        {
            if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
            {
                echo "this doesn't work";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // error this file ext is not allowed
            echo "this doesn't work either";
        }
    }
}
echo "however this works perfectly";
?>
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't output any 'echo' that is included in the first if-statement and children, while the file is uploaded correctly.

Any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: forgot a ';' at the end of the last echo.

Comment: Remove one of the `!` in `if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )` unless that's another typo(?)

Comment: I don't think I should because then it doesn't perform the upload

Comment: See [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23090558/) below. Both `!` needed to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I learned something today about `!!` from [`The Blue Dog (comment)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090090/no-visual-output-after-uploading-file/23090558?noredirect=1#comment35292626_23090558), thanks for the added PHP quirk ;-)

> "Believe it or not, !! is the same as not having them there in the first place, try it and see: $t = true; if(!! $t){ echo "true";}" // The Blue Dog

<strike>Change this line:</strike>

```
if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
```

to

```
if ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
```

and it will work. (tested)

Both `!!` should not be there.

---

```
<?php

//Upload the image
$allow = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

$todir = 'images/';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//    if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?

    if ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
    {
        $info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file

        if ( in_array( end($info), $allow) ) // is this file allowed
        {
            if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
            {
                echo "Success";
            }
        }


        else
        {
            // error this file ext is not allowed
            echo "Sorry, this is now allowed.";
        }
    }

}
// echo "however this works perfectly";
?>
```

Comment: Believe it or not, `!!` is the same as not having them there in the first place, try it and see: `$t = true; if(!! $t){ echo "true";}`

Comment: Well I'll be, I learned something new today. @TheBlueDog cool.

Comment: that seems to work if I'm just being redirected to 'upload_file.php', however if I ajax the form and then try to retrieve 'upload_file.php' output in some '<div>', I don't get anything... but this probably is another question

Comment: Ok, I re-tested OP's code. (groan) there's nothing wrong with it. @TheBlueDog I should delete this.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Just another one of those PHP 'quirks', why anyone would bother with `not-not` is beyond me though ;)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I thought the `!!` were the issue. @user1793646

Comment: @TheBlueDog Quirk's the word. Thanks for that though, in my 4-5 years of PHP'ing, I never knew that.

Comment: ok so in fact the entire script works fine, but when I try to ajax it, nothing is retrieved, I think that's it! You'll see me posting another question in a few minutes

Comment: @user1793646 That would another question yes. (Ajax)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I didn't until I just tried it :D We both learned something new today!

Comment: or should I delete the entire question?

Comment: Actually, no. I think this could prove to be beneficial, what with the `!!` which The Blue Dog brought to my attention. @user1793646

Comment: Sharing the wealth, as it were @TheBlueDog Thanks again bro.

Comment: *" why anyone would bother with `not-not` is beyond me though"* --- I guess it's like when you multiply two negatives, it gives a positive. @TheBlueDog

Answer (score 0):

The correct attribute is

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, little typo but still doesn't change anything if corrected...

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in path or permission.

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$todir;
if(is_dir($path)){
if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
            {
                echo "this doesn't work";
            }
}
else
echo 'Check path '.$path;
```

Comment: however it still uploads perfectly, which would imply that

move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) )

is true and thus the echo should run??

Comment: if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )
-->
if ( !$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )

Comment: doesn't work I'm afraid, the upload wasn't performed

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple of things to work out:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //not sure if what you wrote here was valid, but most commonly it's
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) ) // does file exist
    {
        //we'll use an easier way to find the extension
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ( in_array( $ext, $allow) ) // is this file allowed
        {
            if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
            {
                echo "file uploaded";
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'error uploading: '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // error this file ext is not allowed
            echo "file not allowed";
        }
    }
}
```